# Calculate all possible permutations/combinations, then check if the result is equal to a value

Tags: c#, combinations, permutation

Best way I can explain it is using an example:

You are visiting a shop with $2000, your goal is to have $0 at the end of your trip.
You do not know how many items are going to be available, nor how much they cost.

Say that there are currently 3 items costing $1000, $750, $500.
(The point is to calculate all possible solutions, not the most efficient one.)

You can spend $2000, this means:

```
You can buy the $1000 item 0, 1 or 2 times.
You can buy the $750 item 0, 1 or 2 times.
You can buy the $500 item 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 times.
```

At the end I need to be able to have all solutions, in this case it will be

```
2*$1000
1*$1000 and 2*$500
2*$750 and 1*$500
4*$500
```

Side note: you can't have a duplicate solution (like this)

```
1*$1000 and 2*$500
2*$500 and 1*$1000
```

This is what I tried:

You first call this function using

```
 goalmoney = convert.ToInt32(goalMoneyTextBox.Text);
 totalmoney = Convert.ToInt32(totalMoneyTextBox.Text);
 int[] list = new int[usingListBox.Items.Count];
 Calculate(0, currentmoney, list);
```

The function:

```
    public void Calculate(int level, int money, int[] list)
    {
        string item = usingListBox.Items[level].ToString();
        int cost = ItemDict[item];
        for (int i = 0; i <= (totalmoney / cost); i++)
        {
            int[] templist = list;
            int tempmoney = money - (cost * i);
            templist[level] = i;
            if (tempmoney == goalmoney)
            {
                resultsFound++;
            }
            if (level < usingListBox.Items.Count - 1 && tempmoney != goalmoney) Calculate(level + 1, tempmoney, templist);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Asking for help with a specific issue is more meaningful, just a general "how do you do that?" isn't a great question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Added my current (but broken) function.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be reduced to a well known mathematical problem labeled [Frobenius equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusEquation.html) which is closely related to the well known [Coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). Suppose you have `N` items, where i-th item costs `c[i]` and you need to spent exactly `S`$. So you need to find all non negative integer solutions (or decide whether there are no solutions at all) of equation

```
c[1]*n[1] + c[2]*n[2] + ... + c[N]*n[N] = S
```

where all `n[i]` are unknown variables and each `n[i]` is the number of bought items of i-th type.

This equation can be solved in a various ways. The following function `allSolutions` (I suppose it can be additionally simplified) finds all solutions of a given equation:

```
public static List<int[]> allSolutions(int[] system, int total) {
    ArrayList<int[]> all = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] solution = new int[system.length];//initialized by zeros
    int pointer = system.length - 1, temp;
    out:
    while (true) {
        do { //the following loop can be optimized by calculation of remainder
            ++solution[pointer];
        } while ((temp = total(system, solution)) < total);

        if (temp == total && pointer != 0)
            all.add(solution.clone());
        do {
            if (pointer == 0) {
                if (temp == total) //not lose the last solution!
                    all.add(solution.clone());
                break out;
            }
            for (int i = pointer; i < system.length; ++i)
                solution[i] = 0;
            ++solution[--pointer];
        } while ((temp = total(system, solution)) > total);
        pointer = system.length - 1;
        if (temp == total)
            all.add(solution.clone());
    }
    return all;
}

public static int total(int[] system, int[] solution) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < system.length; ++i)
        total += system[i] * solution[i];
    return total;
}
```

In the above code `system` is array of coefficients `c[i]` and `total` is `S`. There is an obvious restriction: `system` should have no any zero elements (this lead to infinite number of solutions). A slight modification of the above code avoids this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have class `Product` which exposes a property called `Price`, this is a way to do it:

```
public List<List<Product>> GetAffordableCombinations(double availableMoney, List<Product> availableProducts)
{
    List<Product> sortedProducts = availableProducts.OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).ToList();

    //we have to cycle through the list multiple times while keeping track of the current
    //position in each subsequent cycle. we're using a list of integers to save these positions
    List<int> layerPointer = new List<int>();
    layerPointer.Add(0);

    int currentLayer = 0;

    List<List<Product>> affordableCombinations = new List<List<Product>>();
    List<Product> tempList = new List<Product>();

    //when we went through all product on the top layer, we're done
    while (layerPointer[0] < sortedProducts.Count)
    {
        //take the product in the current position on the current layer
        var currentProduct = sortedProducts[layerPointer[currentLayer]];
        var currentSum = tempList.Sum(p => p.Price);

        if ((currentSum + currentProduct.Price) <= availableMoney)
        {
            //if the sum doesn't exeed our maximum we add that prod to a temp list
            tempList.Add(currentProduct);
            //then we advance to the next layer
            currentLayer++;
            //if it doesn't exist, we create it and set the 'start product' on that layer
            //to the current product of the current layer
            if (currentLayer >= layerPointer.Count)
                layerPointer.Add(layerPointer[currentLayer - 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            //if the sum would exeed our maximum we move to the next prod on the current layer
            layerPointer[currentLayer]++;

            if (layerPointer[currentLayer] >= sortedProducts.Count)
            {
                //if we've reached the end of the list on the current layer,
                //there are no more cheaper products to add, and this cycle is complete
                //so we add the list we have so far to the possible combinations
                affordableCombinations.Add(tempList);
                tempList = new List<Product>();

                //move to the next product on the top layer
                layerPointer[0]++;
                currentLayer = 0;
                //set the current products on each subsequent layer to the current of the top layer
                for (int i = 1; i < layerPointer.Count; i++)
                {
                    layerPointer[i] = layerPointer[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return affordableCombinations;
}
```